# Can a shape rolling inside itself reproduce that shape?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, curves

> ***Q***. Is the circle the only shape that, when rolling inside itself,
>   has a point that draws out a scaled copy of itself?

Let $C$ be a simple, closed, smooth curve in the plane.
(Likely "smooth" can be replaced by $C^2$.)
Let $B = s C$, $s \in (0,1)$ be a scaled copy of $C$,
and $p$ some fixed point inside $B$.
Finally, let $A$ be the trace of $p$ as $B$ rolls (without slippage)
inside $C$. An example of what it means to "roll" is provided below:
tangents match at the contact point, and arc length rolled matches
arc length traversed.

My question is whether it is possible for $A$ to be equal to $t C$, $t \in (0,1)$—a scaled copy of $C$—for any curve $C$ that is not a circle?
Clearly the circle has this property, if $p$ is chosen to be the center of $B$.
$C$ could conceivably be nonconvex, and perhaps smoothness need not be assumed.

---

[image: List item]

     

<sup>A $1 \times \frac{1}{2}$ ellipse rolling inside a $2 \times 1$ ellipse;
$p$ slightly off-center.</sup>


     

<sup>(Reload to repeat animation.)</sup>

---

Comment: In order for the trace to be convex and possibly smooth, some assumptions need to be made, such as the curvature of C is greater than the curvature of B at all points of contact.  Gerhard "Or Maybe Always Less Than" Paseman, 2017.03.08.

Comment: In fact, curvature may be the key here.  I bet Robert Bryant could tell you a slick proof that the only possibilities in any dimension are a an n-sphere rolling inside a larger n-sphere, and also that the necessary point must be the center.  Gerhard "Not Good At Differential Geometry" Paseman, 2017.03.08.

Comment: I wonder about gear teeth, which is why I'm open to nonconvex $C$...

Comment: You can consider that.  However, you may come into a situation where you need to "mimic" curvature, possibly with some delay, by a combination of two other curvatures. It may be that linkages might provide more insight into what is possible.  Anyway,  you have to be careful what it means to not slip.  I can see a definition where certain parts of C never get contacted by B.  Gerhard "Contact Can Be A Verb" Paseman, 2017.03.08.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: "for any curve $C$ that is not a circle?"

Comment: maybe checking whether a closed Pythagorean Hodograph Curve with that properties exists is easier.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: Hodographs are new to me. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: the curves that are generated by rolling one curve along another, are called [Roulettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette_(curve)). The Wiki article also contains a characterization of those curves; may be that provides the lever to decide the question.

Comment: Probably not hard to show that the circle is the only curve that works at any scale s.

Answer (score 1):

Refering only to the question as formulated in the title and, ignoring the clarification that aims at giving a precise definition, the answer is yes, namely the non-smooth [Reuleaux Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) if one is willing to accept the [Envelope Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) as the curve that is generated by the rolling curve. Further restrictions are of course that in the initial position a corner of the rolling curve must coincide with a corner of the containing curve and, that the rolling curve must be a copy of the containing curve that is shrunk by an integer multiple of 3 in the case of the Reuleaux triangle.

Smooth Reuleaux triangles will fail to generate a scaled copy of itself because the envelope is an offset-curve, which in turn means that a constant value is *subtracted* from all curvature radii, whereas are a scaled copy would require that all radii are *divided* by a constant value.